# GAE Custom Domain Delegation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-console

I have a Google Application Engine project that is working fine with two Custom Domains pointing at the application.  mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com.  I want to transfer the domain pointers to another GAE project on a second gmail account, and later transfer them back.

I thought this would be as simple as using www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ to make the second account a second owner of the two domains because they are automatically verified through delegation.  This looks to be happening if I use webmaster tools with the second account, I see the sites as I do with the first account.

My plan was then to go into Custom Domains for the first account through https://console.developers.google.com/ and turn off the domains pointing to it and then go to the second account and point the domains to it.

Unfortunately whatever I seem to do I cannot get the other domains to show up in "2. Select the domain ..."  I seem to need to verify the domains, even though delegation should be sufficient.

I could verify by hitting the domain registrar with new settings but it seems a pretty heavy approach when all I am trying to do is get Google to move the domain pointers from one GAE application to another.

Also there will be a long hiatus where the domains are pointing at nothing. I suspect this to be either my complete misunderstanding of the Custom Domain approach or a Google/GAE issue.

I suspect a Google/GAE issue because in the second account some of the descriptions of the delegated ownership domain names have `http://` at the front and this is not true on the first account.
Any suggestions or help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and I had to call Google Apps for Work (renamed from Business) to cancel the original account that housed the domain so it would show up in my second (new) account.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround/alternative which is to verify the domain names using the sub-domain method.  I use 1&1 for my domain names and although it only allows 5 sub-domains I have a spare one I can use.  So I have two sub-domains defined, one for each account as per verify settings in webmaster central.  I can easily flip the domain pointer between the first and second accounts and back again using https://console.developers.google.com/ .  This is partly because the other configuration settings that are necessary when you set up a domain pointer in Custom Domains are always the same for Google, even if the accounts and applications are different.  There is no haitus with this method because the flipping takes effect immediately in Google, although the effect in the web world can take a while with caching occurring all over the place.
I could not used the suggested Google Apps/Business solution as I am not using either.
The conclusion I reach is that delegation of domain names is not really much use and best avoided.